# not able to display the google map with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

1. This initialize will be called from onclick function   function

   ```
   initialize() {
   var branchName =    $( "#preferredBranch option:selected" ).val();
    var lat= null;
    var lng =null;
        if(branchName == '100032' ){

        lat  = 24.4837507;
        lan = 54.3769598;
        }  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
       var mapOptions = {
         center:   new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lan),
         zoom: 9,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
       }
       var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
       google.maps.event.trigger($scope.map.control.getGMap(), "resize"); 
       $('myModal"]').on('shown', function(e) {
           google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
       })
   ```

   ---jsp

   not able to display the google map with bootstrap. while zooming I
   am able to see the google map, otherwise plain google map is coming.
   please help me out to solve the issue

Comment: Can you setup a fiddle (jsfiddle.net) so we can see what actually is going wrong?

Comment: found the solution. added  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function(){
 google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');  thanks for your help

Comment: Fixing it yourself is always better :)